# ¿Como abrir un archivo de excel y ejecutar una macro desde python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Estoy realizando un proyecto en python y la parte final de este pryecto, requiero abrir un archivo .xlsm de excel y ejecutar una macro.

Es posible realizar este paso desde python, es decir, prograbar que vaya a una ruta abra el archivo y ejecute la macro?

Me puede orientar por favor como hacer esto.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

**Importar archivo xlsx**

```
import pandas as pd

ruta_del_archivo = 'Informacion.xlsx'
File = pd.ExcelFile(ruta_del_archivo)
```

Si queremos saber los nombres de las hojas que tiene el libro de Excel que hemos almacenado en la variable File utilizamos la siguiente instrucción. En este caso solamente hay una hoja con nombre 'Datos'.

```
print(File.sheet_names)

['Datos']
```

Se crea una variable que hemos llamado df y se lee el contenido de la hoja 'Datos' utilizando la función parse.

```
df=File.parse('Datos')
```

Imprimimos el contenido de la variable df. Se puede notar que las filas están numeradas desde el 0 hasta el 8. En python el primer índice es el 0.

```
print(df)
```

**Ejecutar macro**

Lo primero es indicarle a python la ruta de tu archivo para eso debes usar:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/usuario/Descargas')   # Te permite cambiar de directorio, aquí ubicas la dirección (carpeta) donde se encuentra el macro

### Opcional
# os.listdir()    # Muestra los archivos que están en el directorio
# os.getcwd()     # Esto pasa el directorio que se definió en os.chdir


os.system("comando_ejecucion macro")   # Aquí lanzas la ejecución de tu macro
```

Para lanzar tu macro desde windows puedes visitar [macros desde linea de comandos (Windows)](https://www.generacodice.com/es/articolo/399346/Forma-de-ejecutar-las-macros-de-Excel-desde-la-l%C3%ADnea-de-comandos-o-archivo-por-lotes)

*Estos datos son generales, ya que desconozco tu sistema operativo, la ruta, y el macro. Espero te pueda servir de ayuda en algo.*

Answer (score 0):

En "comando ejecución macro" que debemos de poner?

Por mucho que le pongo la macro que ejecuta el archivo me dice que no lo reconoce

Le puse esto:
os.system("Main")

porque la macro principal que ejecuta todo se llama Main y me dice que no se reconoce:
"Main" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
[Finished in 1.7s]